# importing javaScript to Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have angular2 application, I want to use in it hlghtta from an external JS file 
**myJSfile.js**

```
var hlghtta = function (b, t, re, c) {
    "use strict";
     .......some functions here
};
module.exports = hlghtta;
```

however I cannot import it into my component with

```
import hlghtta from "hlghtta";
```

I already added **myJSfile.js** to .angular-cli.json
could you please help guys? might be something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Ideally you should have typings but if not you can use this way . You can also check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) on more info

```
declare var hlghtta: any;

import '../../../../hlghtta.js';
export class Component {
    ngOnInit() {
        new hlghtta(params);   
    }
}
```