# How to use Javascript in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi Have a Bootstrap navbar component with javascript like :

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/a35lo

In above example, It has HTML, CSS, and JS, If I want to use above in Angular 4, How can I use above JS directly instead of converting it into typescript.

Comment: If you want to use Angular 4 than you must be convert into typescript.I don't think it is possible without typescript

Comment: You can always use native javascript in typescript

Comment: You don't have to use Typescript at all. You can build your Angular application with JS alone. http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/how-to-do-everything-in-angular2-using-es6/

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, so any JavaScript is valid TypeScript.

Comment: take a look at this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008402/2708210.

Comment: Typescript is just a superset of Javascript.
So you can use javascript inside a typescript file :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to load js file using scriptLoaderService in your component.
then you can use any JQuery or third-party library code in your ts file.

```js
(<any>$('body')).scrollspy({
  target: '#navbar-collapsible',
  offset: 50
});

/* smooth scrolling sections */
(<any>$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')).click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```